# JavaFx 2.2 ColorPicker can't select some colors

Tags: javafx-2, color-picker

I have recently moved to JavaFx 2.2.3 and found there a new component ColorPicker. At the first glance it looks great compared to my own component I've wrote for the old version of JavaFx(which suffered from this component) which is simple and poor. But when I started playing with it I was not able to select some colors with the component. For example I wanted to select a red color(#FF0000) but was not able to do it. It is not present neither among predefined colors nor I can select it from the custom colors' pop-up dialog. Is it a bug? Maybe I am doing something wrong. To be more specific: How to select #FF0000 color with this component?

Comment: yep ,it seems like a bug !